# Developing and deploying Vuejs app with django

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2

I have built a fairly simple web app in [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/), which was running with its default `npm run dev` command with webpack. Vue app was utilizing the api from [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) that I have built using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). And whenever there was a change in Vue app it will automatically hot reload, which is pretty awesome.

Now I would like run the Vue app using django instead of webpack. What I mean is that Django will respond with an html template file, and Vuejs app will run on that html file for a single page application.

What I am doing now is first run this command:

```
npm run build
```

Then I copy the dist/**static/** folder files into the django **static** folder. And finally load it into the template:

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    ...
    <link href="{% static "css/app.e446b60204fec1f9f5510c711523ffca.css" %}" rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="{% static "js/manifest.88376ea5d07804f39ff7.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/vendor.e0e5105739e9947a23e7.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/app.571e9140518a5bae898c.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now later on, if I need to change the Vue app, I have to build it again, copy the files and load it inside the template, which seems pretty lengthy.

So, I am hoping there is better and short way to mix up both Django and Vuejs.

Comment: I think what I would do is change `npm run build` to put the files straight into your django static folder, since there's really no benefit to putting them in the dist/static folder and then transferring them.  I'm not really sure why the generated filenames wouldn't always be the same, which would mean you shouldn't have to change your template at all.  I'm rather new to Vue myself, but hope this helps!

Comment: In addition to @ChristopherShroba maybe [`django-webpack-builder`](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) might help you.

Comment: @ChristopherShroba Yes, I think that's one way to do it. How are you handling the naming of the bulid files though?

Comment: @nik_m Thank you. I will look into that.

Answer (score 6):

There is a great article here explaining how to go about running a Vue app within a django template.

https://ariera.github.io/2017/09/26/django-webpack-vue-js-setting-up-a-new-project-that-s-easy-to-develop-and-deploy-part-1.html

It pretty much explains how to run everything, using the latest Vue app template provided with vue-cli. Additional packages used are django-webpack-loader to render the js packages in the template, and the webpack-bundle-tracker to allow Hot Module Replacement within the django app.

You can play around with the webpack / django static files set up to run the vue app from any location and build the static files to whatever location suits your purpose.

One additional step I took was to write a custom template tag to wrap the render_bundle function in django-webpack-loader. To serve the app after a production build with webpack you need to include:

```
{% render_bundle 'manifest' %}
{% render_bundle 'vendor' %}
{% render_bundle 'app' %}
```

This will throw an error when serving the app from the webpack dev server. Catching that exception will allow it to fail silently and you can develop away with all the benefits of the dev server. Eg.

```
from webpack_loader import utils
from webpack_loader.exceptions import WebpackBundleLookupError
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.simple_tag
def render_bundle(bundle_name, extension=None, config='DEFAULT', attrs=''):
    try:
        tags = utils.get_as_tags(bundle_name, extension=extension, config=config, attrs=attrs)
    except WebpackBundleLookupError as e:
        return''
    return mark_safe('\n'.join(tags))
```